# Issue with non transitive R class migration

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I want to run the non transitive R class migration for my project. As of now I can only do that with Android studio action Refactor > Migrate to Non-Transitive R class... But we have react native code as well which is hosted in npm repository and get added as **node_modules** post running npm ci command. Hence, in our CI/CD, build fails because there are **R** class references in react native libraries.

For example, react native uses an open source library named **react-native-screens** where R class is referenced in **ScreenStackHeaderConfig.kt** class.
[Github Link](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-screens/blob/main/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/rnscreens/ScreenStackHeaderConfig.kt)

I want to know if there is any commandline option available to migrate to Non-Transitive R class or can we do it only for specific modules?

Comment: /gradle.properties -> android.nonTransitiveRClass=true

Comment: @Arnold Brown Adding to module specific gradle.properties is not working. Could you please explain the solution you are saying. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For projects created with earlier versions of Android Studio, update them to use non-transitive R classes by going to **Refactor > Migrate to Non-Transitive R Classes**.

Then it will show you the targets, so you can change manually or auto,

Ex: `com.my.moduleB.R.string.hello` instead of `R.string.hello`.

If you changed them manually , you must

```
/gradle.properties -> android.nonTransitiveRClass=true
```

Answer (score -2):

For who is having the same difficulty, just:

- Go inside gradle.properties and put in `android.nonTransitiveRClass=false`
- Gradle Sync -> Rebuild

I don't know why everyone keep telling to set `android.nonTransitiveRClass=true`, because that's opposite from what we really want.